# codeigniter autoload default controller, cannot load view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have controller home with function index which loads view index under home directory

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {      
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home/index');
    }
}
```

I've changed default controller call inside routes.php to home instead of welcome.

Now, when navigate to `mysite.com` I've got error message

```
Unable to load the requested file: `home/index.php`
```

But when I type inside address `mysite.com/home` everything loads.

What can be a problem?

Thanks

Update:
`.htaccess` is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|Images|Content|Scripts|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Could you illustrate your `routes.php`, `.htaccess` or other things might help, please?

Comment: You mean you changed default controller call inside `routes.php` ?

Comment: yes, inside routes.php :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your config/config.php as

```
   $config['index_page'] = '';
```